# JavaScript не отображается переменная в методе. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript

Есть класс

```js
const DBService = class {
    constructor(){
        this.SERVER = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
        this.API = ***;
    }
    getData = async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Не удалось получить данные по запросу ${url}`)
        }
    }
    
    getCard = query => {
        this.temp = `${this.SERVER}/search/tv?api_key=${this.API}&language=ru-RU&query=${query}`;
        return this.getData(this.temp);
    }
    getPage = page => {
        return this.getData(this.temp + '&page=' + page);
    }
};
```

получаю `this.temp` через консоль смотрел отображается
`new DBService().getCard(value).then(renderSearch)`
`this.temp` уже не показывается пишет `undefined`
`new DBService().getPage(value).then(renderSearch)`
и получается вот такой запрос http://127.0.0.1:5500/undefined&page=2
(`renderSearch` обычная функция чтобы появлялись карточки с фильмами)
Я мог бы записать `this.temp` в конструктор но тогда запрос сделаный в поиске (`query`) не будет отображаться в `this.temp` а без этого никуда

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы `this.temp` в `getPage` отображалась также как в `getCard`

Comment: так ты нигде не устанавливаешь `this.temp` поэтому и получаешь `undefined`

Comment: @Grundy
Не понял можешь по подробнее я же задал значение this.temp в getCard и хочу использовать его в getPage

Comment: @ВоваГусев а где вызов getCard?

Comment: @AlexeyTen DBService().getCard(value).then(renderSearch) вот

Comment: а потом ты создал новый объект, у которого не вызывался getCard, и соответственно не заполнялся this.temp

Comment: @Grundy точно спасибо